# Special objects in a category - terminology

Tags: ct.category-theory

For an object $A$ in a category $\mathfrak{C}$, consider the following property.

($*$) For every object $B$ in $\mathfrak{C}$, the set of morphisms $\text{Hom}(B,A)$ is either empty or consists solely of isomorphisms.

How does one call objects $A$ satisfying ($*$)?

Comment: Why do you think that such terminology exists?

Comment: Also, could you give an example of object with such property, which is not a _strict initial object_ and not an object in a groupoid?

Comment: From my point of view, property ($*$) is to the property "being terminal" just like "maximal" is to "greatest" in partially ordered sets. This analogy leads me to suspecting that such a terminology exists.

Comment: As for an example, take an inductive partially ordered set which does not possess a greatest element.

Comment: Seems like this property is actual only for preorders: if $C$ is locally small and complete, then such object $A$ has no non-trivial automorphisms...

Comment: @Oskar For a group $G$, the category of transitive $G$-sets has $G$ itself as such object. There are similar examples coming from (categorical) Galois theory; related example - universal covering of a space in the category of all coverings.

Comment: If $\mathfrak{C}$ is locally small and cocomplete, an object $A$, satisfying (*), is simply a strict initial object of some full subcategory $\mathfrak{B}$ of $\mathfrak{C}$. Indeed, if $B$ is some other object of $\mathfrak{C}$, such that $\text{hom}(A,B)$ is nonempty, then we have:
$$
\text{hom}(A,B)\cong\text{hom}((\coprod_{\text{hom}(A,B)}A),B)\cong\prod_{\text{hom}(A,B)}\text{hom}(A,B)\cong\text{hom}(A,B)^{\text{hom}(A,B)},
$$
which implies that $\text{hom}(A,B)\cong\{*\}$.

Comment: That's a nice idea, Oskar, thank you. But I am really looking only for the terminology.

Comment: @Oskar: This is not addressing the question. The question didn't ask for the hom set being one-elemented, but to contain isomorphisms only.

Comment: The property you mention is this: $A$ has this property iff the connected component of  $A$ is a groupoid.

Comment: @ADe Seems that you read my comment inattentively. It claims that in a good class of categories all hom-sets from such objects are one-elemented.

Comment: @ADe Also, $\varnothing$ is a strict initial object of $\mathbf{Set}$, but the connected component of $\varnothing$ is obviously not a groupoid.

Answer (score 1):

If you define the connected component $C(A)$ of an object $A$ in a category $C$ as the full subcategory of all objects $B$ such that $Hom(B,A)$ is not empty, then the property (*) is equivalent to saying that $C(A)$ is a groupoid.

Comment: This is an interesting condition. And if it holds then the object $A$ is called "..."?

Comment: *If you define the connected component...* then I would be using well established mathematical language in a very peculiar way.

Comment: As @PaulTaylor says, that's not the standard meaning of "connected component".  But along the same lines one could say that the co-slice category $A/C$ is a groupoid.

Comment: @MikeShulman For $\mathfrak C=$ transitive $G$-sets, $A=G$ (the example from my comment) the co-slice is not a groupoid.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე I think Mike meant _slice_-category...

Comment: Oh yes, I misread the question, sorry.  Slice category.